# Where do I place an app icon? (cross-platform)

Tags: icons

I have an app I'm developing for Linux and it has an icon. I'm certain that no icon themes contain my app's icon yet. Is there a pre-existing icon theme installed on every system that I can place the icon into so that the .desktop file can find it? Particularly one that is used for the app's stock icon in case it's not in the user's own theme? This needs to be deployable on all Linux distributions via a BASH script and/or distribution-specific packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't place your app icon into a theme; you place it into a directory related to your application and then the desktop file points to that.

For example, you might want to put your file in `/usr/share/myapp/myicon.ico` and then your desktop file has the line `Icon=/usr/share/myapp/myicon.ico`

Comment: That's not true, the [Icon Theme Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/0.13/ar01s07.html) clearly states that you put it in `$prefix/share/icons/hicolor/*/apps`. hicolor is the default fallback theme.